# Integrate Projects in a single project

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git, version-control

I have same xcode project on two deferent macbooks with different code.we need to merge that code but we are not using any git account.We need to merge same file as well,I mean we have same viewcontroller and added two people add a code in single view controller How i can merge it.
For example:

> I have a view controller Name "XYZ"and Person 1 added "Login Method"
>   into "XYZ" and person 2 added "Sign up Method" into XYZ. and both code
>   are on deferent macbook without any git account how I can `merge`
>   that.

Comment: Cmd+C, cmd+V is your friend

Comment: Use version control, use Git. You can use it in existing projects.

Comment: can you explain little bit.How I need to upload both code on git and then merge .

Comment: @Marina-MSFT Thanks for your answer but I can't try this, Because I have done manually before your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use the git tag, I will provide the way to do version control by git.
First, please sign up account for [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/account/signin/?next=/dashboard/overview) (free for private repository) or [github](https://github.com/) (only free for public repository). And create a repository. They are as the remote git repository(repo).

Then use [git bash](https://git-scm.com/downloads) for local repository.

In one macbook, use these steps:

1. `git clone <URL for your bitbucket or github repo>`
2. `cd reponame`
3. copy your xcode project in reponame folder
4. `git add .`
5. `git commit -am 'code version from first macbook'`
6. `git push`

Now the code in the first macbook is pushed in your remote repo.

In the other macbook, use these steps:

1. In an empty folder, use `git init`
2. copy your xcode project in this folder
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -am 'code version from second macbook'`
5. `git remote add origin <URL for your bitbucket or github repo>`
6. `git pull origin master`
7. Now the code from macbook1 is merging in macbook2
8. If there has conflict files, you should check and save them, and then use `git add .` and `git commit -m 'solve merge conflict'`.
9. Now this is the version that you merge the different macbooks together. You can push the version in remote repo by `git push`.

More git related, you can refer [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Answer (score 0):

Any version control system comes to handy in this kind of situations. Merging manually is the option available other than version control system. Either merge using version control system like git or manually merge the files which is very hard to workout.